# Cache Management with Numerous Similar Database Queries

Tags: caching

I'm trying to introduce caching into an existing server application because the database is starting to become overloaded.

Like many server applications we have the concept of a data layer. This data layer has many different methods that return domain model objects. For example, we have an employee data access object with methods like:

- findEmployeesForAccount(long accountId)
- findEmployeesWorkingInDepartment(long accountId, long departmentId)
- findEmployeesBySearch(long accountId, String search)

Each method queries the database and returns a list of Employee domain objects.

Obviously, we want to try and cache as much as possible to limit the number of queries hitting the database, but how would we go about doing that?

I see a couple possible solutions:

1) We create a cache for each method call. E.g. for findEmployeesForAccount we would add an entry with a key account-employees-accountId. For findEmployeesWorkingInDepartment we could add an entry with a key department-employees-accountId-departmentId and so on. The problem I see with this is when we add a new employee into the system, we need to ensure that we add it to every list where appropriate, which seems hard to maintain and bug-prone.

2) We create a more generic query for findEmployeesForAccount (with more joins and/or queries because more information will be required). For other methods, we use findEmployeesForAccount and remove entries from the list that don't fit the specified criteria.

I'm new to caching so I'm wondering what strategies people use to handle situations like this? Any advice and/or resources on this type of stuff would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with the same question myself for a few weeks now... so consider this a half-answer at best. One bit of advice that has been working out well for me is to use the Decorator Pattern to implement the cache layer. For example, here is an article detailing this in C#:

http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/building-a-cachedrepository-via-strategy-pattern/

This allows you to literally "wrap" your existing data access methods without touching them. It also makes it very easy to swap out the cached version of your DAL for the direct access version at runtime quite easily (which can be useful for unit testing).

I'm still struggling to manage my cache keys, which seem to spiral out of control when there are numerous parameters involved. Inevitably, something ends up not being properly cleared from the cache and I have to resort to heavy-handed ClearAll() approaches that just wipe out everything. If you find a solution for cache key management, I would be interested, but I hope the decorator pattern layer approach is helpful.